# Finding the Translation between two pointclouds using ICP algorithm

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, robotics, point-clouds

I have two pointclouds of an object one is the target pointcloud and the other is the real-time pointcloud from a robot.Both the pointclouds are taken at the same distance,point from the object . My goal is to make the robot move till the object,by using ICP algorithm and getting a transformation matrix.

Using the PCL I have tried to implement the ICP algorithm and I am getting a Transformation Matrix, but the translation is not correct. Suppose if the robot is at a distance of 40cm from the object,then the translation is only shows 10cm.

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
                icp.setInputSource(cloud);
                icp.setInputTarget(ideal_cloud);
                icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon(-1.797e+5);
                icp.setMaximumIterations(50);
                icp.setRANSACIterations(2000);
                icp.setTransformationEpsilon(1e-3);
                pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final;
                icp.align(Final);

                //Print Final Transformation and score
                std::cout << "has converged:" << icp.hasConverged() << " score: " <<
                icp.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
```

As far as I know the ICP algorithm is used to find the best-fit between two pointclouds, and it gives a transformation matrix which tells how much translation and rotation is needed to align both the pointclouds. But I am not sure why I am getting the translation with such large error.

Comment: I suggest that generate some fake data for yourself. Then apply a known transformation and rotation. Is the error near zero? Can you reconstruct your translation and transformation? If this is the case you might add some noise to your points and watch what happens in this case.

Comment: You have a slight misunderstanding of `ICP`'s power. `ICP` is usually used as the last step to do a fine alignment after an initial alignment. `ICP` is very error prone when the two pointclouds are not initially aligned. Have a look at [SAC-IA](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_initial_alignment.html) for initial alignment of point clouds.

Comment: @kanstar I looked into SAC-IA and it was mentioned that it is used for 3d registration, since I am using 2d lidar data is it possible to use SAC-IA, bear with me if this a stupid question, I am an amateur and not familiar.

Comment: @kanstar should I make any changes to the ICP code that I have shown above,like any changes in the parameters?

Comment: @Goalscorer Yeah you can use SAC-IA for "2D" data, which is essentially "3D" data where all the points are on the XY plane.